# 2-sphere as submanifold of cylinder

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

I want to prove or disprove the following statement: Exist $f:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ x $S^1$ smooth, inyective and with $df_p$ inyective for all $p\in S^2$.

I note that since $S^2$ is compact if that function exist have to be and embedding.

Comment: $S^2$ is simply connected, so such a map can be lifted to the universal covering space $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then Borsuk-Ulam in dimension $2$ yields a contradiction.

Comment: Actually, BS is way too strong for the conclusion, you can just say that if there is a smooth embedding $f: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, then the image of $S^2$ minus a point is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, precompact, which has a single point in its boundary (because the  image of $S^2$ is compact) so there is a contradiction.

Comment: @Mindlack why you are taking $f$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and not to $S^1$ x $\mathbb{R}$, is because the lifting? Have some argument without a lifting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On $\mathbb{R}\times S^{1}$ we have the angle form $d\theta$, which is a closed nowhere vanishing one-form. If there would exist $f:S^{2}\rightarrow S^{1}\times\mathbb{R}$ with $(df)_{p}$ injective at all $p\in S^{2}$, then $f^{*}d\theta$ would be a closed nowhere vanishing one-form on $S^{2}$.

This is a contradiction: every closed one-form on $S^{2}$ must vanish at some point. Indeed, since the de Rham cohomology group $H^{1}(S^{2})$ is trivial, every closed one-form $\alpha\in\Omega^{1}(S^{2})$ is exact: $\alpha=dg$ for some $g\in C^{\infty}(S^{2})$. But then $g$ is a continuous function on a compact domain, so it reaches a maximum in some point $p\in S^{2}$, which implies $\alpha_{p}=(dg)_{p}=0$.

Comment: thank you, but can give me the angle form explicit defined? Because I'm really new working with this.

Comment: @PeterLanguilla The angle form $d\theta$ is the one-form described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060864/non-vanishing-one-form-on-the-circle. But note that we could have taken any closed nowhere vanishing one-form on $\mathbb{R}\times S^{1}$, the proof would still work. For instance, if $h$ is the coordinate on $\mathbb{R}$ then $dh$ is also a closed nowhere vanishing one-form on $\mathbb{R}\times S^{1}$.